# Change default new excel workbook name from "Book1"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, default-settings

Is there a way in Excel to modify the default name of a newly created workbook from Book1, Book2 etc., ideally via VBA? AFAIK this follows the PC regional/language settings so it is defined somewhere.

I am aware that to change a workbook's name, it is necessary to "SaveAs" it, however I do not want to change the name, I want it to be set to that name already in the moment the workbook is created.

Comment: What do you want the default name to be? You can try to have excel start up with a template file, which can have a custom name...

Comment: @Dave I am building a plugin that will create a new separate workbook ad hoc and then allow the user to work with it using other procedures, which need to be able to identify that workbook. IMO the best way is if I can have control over the workbook name, but I specifically do not want to save that workbook because it is just a temporary object for the user to interface with the information I want it to contain.

Comment: then what is the point of a custom name? And additionally, what is the issue with saving it temporarily and then deleting it once it isn't needed? I know those don't answer your question, but I haven't used VBA in a while, so I don't know if that is possible. It might be though...

Comment: @Dave The point is that w/o the custom name, I will need to devise a method for the additional procedures to identify the newly created wb (Book1? Book2? etc.) using its contents and I may have issues with duplicates whereas the name will give me control over both aspects. I don't want to pollute the user's drive wiith saving the file (which can get rather large) or worry about figuring out when it should be deleted.

Comment: it seems from here that you can't change the workbook name without saving:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-vba-to-rename-open-workbooks-without-saving-them.51227/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't change the workbook name without saving the file.

From the Microsoft docs:

> The Name property returns the workbook name. You cannot set the name by using this property; if you need to change the name, use the SaveAs method to save the workbook under a different name.

source: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook#:~:text=The%20Name%20property%20returns%20the,workbook%20under%20a%20different%20name.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook#:%7E:text=The%20Name%20property%20returns%20the,workbook%20under%20a%20different%20name.)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this and I have already indicated as much in the question. I do not seek to change that property, instead I want to create a new workbook with the property already set to what I want it to be. Hence why I am asking how to change the default name from "Book1" etc. to something else.

Comment: from your question "modify the default name of a newly created workbook" implies (to my understanding, correct me if I am wrong) that you want to change an already-created workbook